# MySQL return summed values and a virtual column as (count - sum)

Tags: mysql

I have a table as follows:
`log (log_id, log_success (bool), log_created)`

I would like to SELECT and return 3 columns `date` `success` and `no_success`, where the former does not exist in table and finally aggregate them by day.

I have created this query:

```
SELECT
log_created as 'date'
COUNT(*) AS 'count',
SUM(log_success) AS 'success'
SUM('count' - 'success') AS 'no_success'
FROM send_log
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(log_created, '%Y-%m-%d');
```

Would I be able to achieve it with this query? Is my syntax correct?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Would I be able to achieve it with this query? Is my syntax correct?"* No select aliases can't be reused on the same select level you need to replace  `SUM('count' - 'success') AS 'no_success'` with `SUM(COUNT(*) - SUM(log_success)) AS 'no_success'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reuse an alias defined in the select within the same select clause.  The reason for this is that it might not even have been defined when you go to access it.  But, you easily enough can repeat the logic:

```
SELECT
    log_created AS date,
    SUM(log_success) AS success,
    COUNT(*) - SUM(log_success) AS no_success,
FROM send_log
GROUP BY
    log_created;
```

I don't know why you are calling `DATE_FORMAT` in the *group by* clause of your query.  `DATE_FORMAT` is usually a presentation layer function, which you call because you want to view a date formatted a certain way.  Since it appears that `log_created` is already a date, there is no need to call `DATE_FORMAT` on it when aggregating.  You also should not even need in the select clause, because the default format for a MySQL date is already `Y-m-d`.

Comment: excellent, now re `COUNT(*) AS count`, I basically don't need it since im not using the alias, correct?
and re your question, I am trying to aggregate results by **day**, so I thought I need to stipulate the date format, correct me on the above plz, thx!

Comment: Then remove `count` from the query if you don't need it.  When you aggregate by a date in MySQL, you are aggregating by day.  This is what a date is.

Answer (score 0):

You must select `DATE_FORMAT(log_created, '%Y-%m-%d')` if you want to group by this. 
Also you can get the `no_success` counter with `SUM(abs(log_success - 1))`

```
SELECT
  DATE_FORMAT(log_created, '%Y-%m-%d') date,
  SUM(log_success) log_success,
  SUM(abs(log_success - 1)) no_success
  FROM send_log
GROUP BY date;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ubw1H5Z32py2bH9DXYx5Gn/0)